# enter value to windows azure marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I'm creating account on Windows azure Marketplace   [datamarket.azure.com](https://datamarket.azure.com)

I'm trying to Get data from Microsoft Azure Marketplace from source 
Multivariate Linear Regression API built with Azure Machine Learning
but I'm stuck

[image]

What is the value that I have to enter to download that data?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To use this API, you would need to enter data in the following format. 
Example:

> 10;5;2,18;1;6,6;5.3;2.1,7;5;5,22;3;4,12;2;1,NA;3;4

The output from the API would be:

> V1 V2 V3
>   8.27930722051854 20.1000487872874 7.65005575689992

For more details on how to use the API, pls refer to: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-r-csharp-multivariate-linear-regression/